# JAAS Authentication in WildFly Swarm

Tags: java, authentication, jakarta-ee, jaas, wildfly-swarm

I'm developing a small website using angular frontend and JAX-RS REST services for the backend.
I would like to secure all pages and REST services such that only authenticated users can access the pages and REST services. I'm using WildFly Swarm as my application server and would like to store users and roles in a custom (MySQL) database.
I've only ever worked with JSF and WebSphere application server before, and I've used Windows Active Directory for authentication, so I'm lost here and I didn't find any relevant tutorials or articles on what I should do.

Here's what I did so far

web.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
    "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
<web-app>
<display-name>My Web App</display-name>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Admin Resource</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/administration/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>

    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>

    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>User Resource</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/pages/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>

    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>

    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>../login.html</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>../login-failed.html</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>

<security-role>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
</security-role>
</web-app>
```

project-defaults.yml:

```
swarm:
  context:
    path: /my-app
  datasources:
    data-sources:
      authentication-db:
        driver-name: mysql
        connection-url: jdbc:mysql://mysql-host:3306/AUTHDB
        user-name: root
        password: P@ssw0rd
```

I have 2 questions:

1. How do I specify the database and table as the source for users and roles?
2. How do I implement the actual login process? I have created a LoginServlet that is called when the login.html page is submitted, and tried the line below but it didn't work

   ```
       response.sendRedirect("j_security_check?j_username=" + username + "&j_password=" + password);
   ```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have look at this [example code](https://github.com/thorntail/thorntail-examples/blob/master/security/jaas/form/src/main/resources/project-defaults.yml)

1. It shows how to specify the database table query for the users and roles
2. Defines a form login configuration